# How to parse a name that is a string in LastName, FirstName format into a list in 'Firstname', 'LastName' format?

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I am trying to take a string that has the format "LastName, FirstName" and turn it into a list that reads 'FirstName', 'LastName'.

I have already tried this code:

```
for key in name:
    name = "LastName, FirstName"
    parse_name = name.split(',')

    print(parse_name)
```

And it prints:
['LastName', 'FirstName']

So I am almost there I hope.

However I would also like for the code to be able to use the line below for example by using the above function:

```
parse_name('Jordan, Michael')
```

and return a list
['Michael', 'Jordan']

Comment: Just flip the list: `parse_name = parse_name[::-1]`.

Comment: Reverse the list of names by using `reverse()`. Example: `parse_name.reverse()` This will modify `parse_name` in place and then be in order of FirstName LastName. [python docs on datastructures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def parse_name(name):

    lst = name.split(',') # this line will split the string into two words

    lst.reverse() # this will reverse the list 
    print(lst) # print the list
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had gotten ```None``` as Ilja had said but now it works great!

Comment: okay great, can you give the answer a vote or accept it.@doublepancake84

Comment: Return the list instead of printing it. If you want to print as a demo, print the result of calling the function, not in the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of two elements, you can use Python's multiple assignment to flip the values around:

```
>>> mylist
    ["A", "B"]
>>> mylist[0], mylist[1] = mylist[1], mylist[0]
>>> mylist
    ["B", "A"]
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume two elements if it's arbitrary user input. The first thing a user will do is give you the name `Einstein, Albert, Dr.`.